# Hardware Instancing for Primitives

Tags: xna, hardware

I have read about hardware instancing.
I wanted to apply it to primitives instead of models.
But my question is:
I want to draw a circle build by vertices(in total 6300 Vertices for all circles)

**Do I have to set a transform matrix for every vertex?**

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what MSDN has to say on `GraphicsDevice.DrawInstancedPrimitives`

> This method provides a mechanism for gathering vertex shader input data from different streams at different frequencies (typically by interpreting one data stream as a per-instance world transform); this approach requires a custom shader to interpret the input data. For more information, see DrawInstancedPrimitives in XNA Game Studio 4.0. [Tell me more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevice.drawinstancedprimitives.aspx)

Returning to your question:

> Do I have to set a transform matrix for every vertex?

No you don't.  The instance (not each vertex) will have a transform that you bind to your shader prior to rendering.  A model/instance will have a transform describing it's position in the world. Each vertex is essentially a *relative* coordinate describing an offset from the model's origin.

e.g. courtesy of [Shawn Hargreaves Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/06/17/drawinstancedprimitives-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx)

```
float4x4 WorldViewProj;

void InstancingVertexShader(inout float4 position : POSITION0,
                            in float4x4 world : TEXCOORD0)
{
    position = mul(mul(position, transpose(world)), WorldViewProj);
}
```

...your XNA code: again courtesy of [Shawn Hargreaves Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/06/17/drawinstancedprimitives-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx)

```
instanceVertexBuffer.SetData(instanceTransformMatrices, 0, numInstances, SetDataOptions.Discard);

graphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffers(modelVertexBuffer, new VertexBufferBinding(instanceVertexBuffer, 0, 1));
graphicsDevice.Indices = indexBuffer;
instancingEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();

graphicsDevice.DrawInstancedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0,
                                       modelVertexBuffer.VertexCount, 0,
                                       indexBuffer.IndexCount / 3,
                                       numInstances);
```

Comment: Thank you! I have just one little question: Do I need to define an own VertexDeclaration or am I able to use the VertexDeclaration of examplary VertexPositionColor

Comment: @λExpression You're welcome.  I'm not sure on that sadly.  The example shown [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/06/17/drawinstancedprimitives-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx) is using a custom declaration but I do not know if that is required.

Comment: Howdy dear friend. I think I can use my own vertexbuffer with the own declaration. Probably it is handled seperatly, as You can see "  graphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffers(modelVertexBuffer, new VertexBufferBinding(instanceVertexBuffer, 0, 1));" Thank you anyway